# How to send message with information in JSON format using telegram bot?

Tags: python, json, aiogram

I'm trying to send this information as a message with using telegram bot. But, when I tryed to send message I had a eror: card = f'{hbold("ExchangeName: ")}{(item.get("exchange_name"))}\n' 
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'. How I can fix it?

```
    "name_of_coin": "Bitcoin",
    "marketPairs": [
        {
            "exchange_name": "Binance",
            "market_url": "https://www.binance.com/en/trade/BTC_USDT",
            "price": 49516.15001013148,
            "last_update": "2021-12-05T12:32:54.000Z",
            "exchange_id": 270
        },
        {
            "exchange_name": "Coinbase Exchange",
            "market_url": "https://pro.coinbase.com/trade/BTC-USD",
            "price": 49610.79,
            "last_update": "2021-12-05T12:32:55.000Z",
            "exchange_id": 89
        },
        {
            "exchange_name": "Bitfinex",
            "market_url": "https://www.bitfinex.com/t/BTC:USD",
            "price": 49586.15351025,
            "last_update": "2021-12-05T12:32:53.000Z",
            "exchange_id": 37
        },
        {
            "exchange_name": "FTX",
            "market_url": "https://ftx.com/trade/BTC/USDT",
            "price": 49508.56563407031,
            "last_update": "2021-12-05T12:32:53.000Z",
            "exchange_id": 524
        }
]
```

My code:

```
with open(file_path) as file:
        data = json.load(file)

    for item in data:

        card = f'{hbold("ExchangeName: ")}{(item.get("exchange_name"))}\n' \
        f'{hbold("MarketUrl: ")}{(item.get("market_url"))}\n' \
        f'{hbold("Price: ")}{(item.get("price"))}\n' \
        f'{hbold("LastUpdated: ")}{(item.get("last_update"))}\n' \
        f'{hbold("ExchangeId: ")}{(item.get("exchange_id"))}\n' \

        await message.answer(card)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's do it

```
with open(file_path) as file:
        data = json.load(file)
```

We need to get values from dictionary key named 'marketPairs', then we need to write that:

```
for item in data['marketPairs']:
```

Now we need to use string formatting **correctly** to make it right.
Do not close quotes until the end of the string, please. Look at this:

```
  card = f'ExchangeName: {item["exchange_name"]}\n\
  MarketURL: {item["market_url"]} etc.'
```

I used \n\ without qoutes  firstly for new line in output(symbol \n), then for newline in code (symbol )
Well, then you may use send_message from aiogram lib. Because answer is using after user's message but 'send_message' doesn't wait user's response.

```
  await bot.send_message(user_id, card)
```